# Python - Exercicio de Tabuada- For - Matriz

Tags: python, funções, python-2.7, matriz, for

Boa Noite!
Estou tentando criar um programa de tabuada usando for e matriz, meu codigo esta assim no momento:

def crie_matriz(linhas, colunas, valor):

```
    matriz = [] 
    for i in range(linhas):
        linha = []

        for j in range(colunas):
            valor = i*j
            linha.append(valor)
        matriz.append(linha),"\n"

    return matriz
```

A = crie_matriz(11,11,11)
print(A)

Ele funciona o problema é que no Console so estou recebendo os resultados da multiplicação, quando na verdade o que eu desejo é receber:

[1 x  1 = 1]
[1 x  2 = 2]
[1 x  3 = 3]
[1 x  4 = 4]
[1 x  5 = 5]
[1 x  6 = 6]
[1 x  7 = 7]
[1 x  8 = 8]
[1 x  9 = 9]
[1 x 10 = 10]

É isto que eu quero receber, mas não apenas da tabuada do 1, e sim a tabuada completa uma do lado da outra. Alguém pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Ao preencher a matriz, você pode colocar na lista `linha` não somente o valor, mas a informação que você quer:

`linha.append('{} x {} = {}'.format(i, j, valor))`

Dê uma olhada para saber mais sobre [formatação de strings](https://pyformat.info/).

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela Ajuda, deu super certo! Vlw meu amigo.